# Can anyone point me in the right direction if its possible to get object values form a .net website into salesforce

Tags: apex, webservices, connect-api

Can anyone point me in the right direction if its possible build a webservice to get object values form a .net website into salesforce. If there are articles which explain this topic and if it possible in 2 directions for example with SOAP?. I get a lot of information about SF to .net but not the other way around from .net to SF. Maybe im not using the correct search words in english.

Comment: The logic is the inverse of creating .net data-  you take your .net data and turn it into a salesforce object, then run an insert operation with that data. See the [SOAP Create documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_create.htm).

Comment: If you have a more specific question, that the examples in the documentation do not answer, try making an [edit] to your question to reflect that.